# Is there any other way to get the value of the html textbox in VB.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Other than Request.Form("example") which use the name of the textbox. I want to know if there is any other way to get the value rather than using the Request.Form. I hope you guys understand what I mean and I hope this is not a dumb question. As I'm having problem using the name to get the value of what the textbox consist.

So I thought of using the id to get the value do tell me if that could work.And I would also like to know how it works.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

If Not IsPostBack Then

For Each row As DataRow In cardDT.Rows

                    Literal1.Text += "<tr>"
                    Literal1.Text += "<td><input type='text' id='test" & i & "'  name='test" & i & "' value='" & row("Date") & "'  maxlength='20'></td>"
                    Literal1.Text += "<td><input id='Checkbox1' type='checkbox' name='chk" & i & "' /></td>"
                    Literal1.Text += "</tr>"

                    i += 1

                Next
                Literal1.Text += " </table>"
End Sub
```

This is the button, for now is just check the value stored in request.form but when I click on this button I receive an error when I used the name:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

 Dim i = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In EmployeeDt.Rows
            Dim t = Request.Form("test" & i)
            If Request.Form("check" & i) <> "" Then

                  MsgBox("check" & i & "  " & t)
            End If
            i += 1
        Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: So how do you know which textbox value you want if you don't know its name?

Comment: For example if I could use the textbox id to get the value I wonder if that is possible?

Comment: Why are you not setting the `id` attribute ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways. You can choose which one suits your needs:

1. Change your html input control to `asp:TextBox` control. This will still render in the browser as html input anyways. So it shouldn't make a difference, but you would be able to access it in your code-behind. You can then get its value by `ControlId.Text`.
2. Just add the `RunAt="Server"` attribute on your html input (textbox) control, and you can access it in the code-behind as any other server side control. You can then probably get it value by `ControlId.Value`.

Comment: OK I see that you posted the code now. I was assuming static design-time control on the aspx page. Nevertheless, this answer may help others in need. I will post a different solution.